# How to understand subcall "sub ($c) {...}"?

Tags: perl, mojolicious-lite

I'm reading a mojo example from:
https://mojolicious.org/
Below is the code:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;

# Render template "index.html.ep" from the DATA section
get '/' => sub ($c) {
  $c->render(template => 'index');
};

......
```

My question is how to get this piece of code compiled by perl? Usually I'll code subcalls as:

```
get '/' => sub {
      my $c = shift;
      $c->render(template => 'index');
    };
```

This could be compiled well by strawberry perl. While the example code from mojo got errors:

```
D:\Source\test_code\mojotest>perl mojo3.pl daemon
Illegal character in prototype for ? : $c at mojo3.pl line 4.
Illegal character in prototype for ? : $c at mojo3.pl line 9.
Illegal character in prototype for ? : $c, $msg at mojo3.pl line 10.
```

Could anyone tell why?

Comment: What's the output of `perl -MMojolicious::Lite -le'print for $], $Mojolicious::Lite::VERSION'`? (Replace the single quotes  with double quotes if using the `cmd` shell.)

Comment: You are probably using a very new version of Mojolicious and the latest documentation, but your Perl is too old.

Comment: I'm using latest strawberry, v5.26.

Comment: Could it be a problem about "prototypes", a subroutine that is defined as "sub fun($arg) { $arg....}". Is there any specifical settings in perl for it?

Comment: There's a new feature in recent Perls called _signatures_, which replaces the _prototypes_. Prototypes in Perl are `sub foo ($$$) { ... }` and tell Perl what kind (not type) of argument to expect. They are usually discouraged. Signatures allow you to do `sub foo ($bar, $baz) { ... }` instead of `sub foo { my ($bar, $baz) = @_; ... }`. The `-signatures` on the `use Mojo::Lite` should turn the feature on for you, but maybe your Mojo version is older than that feature? Which one is it? If @ikegami's code didn't help, do `perl -MMojolicious::Lite\ 99` with a space after the backslash ``\``.

Comment: `Mojolicious::Lite -signatures` just enables the `signatures` feature introduced in Perl v5.20. To see if your perl can use this feature, see if this code compiles:

`perl -Mexperimental=signatures -e "sub foo($x) { }"`